# What is the gcc cpu-type that includes support for RDTSCP?

Tags: gcc, x86, intel, rdtsc

I am using RDTSCP to replace LFENCE;RDTSC sequences and also get the processor ID back so that I know when I'm comparing TSC values after the thread was rescheduled to another CPU.

To ensure I don't run RDTSCP on a too old machine I fallback to RDTSC after a CPUID check (using libcpuid).  I'd like to try using the gcc multiple target attribute functionality instead of a CPUID call:

```
int core2_func (void) __attribute__ ((__target__ ("arch=core2")));
```

The [gcc manual lists a number of cpu families](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options) (haswell, skylake, ...).  How would I find which cpu family first introduced RDTSCP?

Comment: Intel's instruction-set manual (see the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), or this [HTML extract](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RDTSCP.html)) only tells you what CPUID feature-bit to check for each instruction.  (Only documenting things by microarchitecture for things that predate CPUID in p5).  To find what CPU introduced what instruction, I normally check Wikipedia.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter hasn't been useful here, though.  Maybe look in a table of CPUID dumps if one exists, and check the feature bit.  Of course, if you're actually running a CPUID instruction in your program at runtime, you should just check the specified feature bit.

Comment: Using the ifunc attribute directly, you can specify your own resolver, in particular one testing the appropriate cpuid bit, instead of relying on the predefined targets.

Comment: Looks like clang doesn't implement the gcc target attribute (nor does it implement the ifunc attribute that Marc mentioned in his comment), so I won't be able to exploit this even if I knew the right arch setting to use.

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#target-gnu-target (the doc doesn't mention multiple targets, so I don't know if that's supported) http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#ifunc-gnu-ifunc (if you are using a Mac, too bad for you)

Answer (score 1):

All AMD processors since the K8 Hammer support `RDTSCP`.

On Intel processors, `RDTSCP` is supported on Nehalem and later, Silvermont and later, and Knights Landing and later.

Comment: I found this question while looking for duplicates for [Detect if processor has RDTSCP at compile time](//stackoverflow.com/q/32357513) as well.  That's good info about what HW has what, but if you're doing this hopefully you can get GCC to dispatch based on a custom CPUID bit like Marc Glisse suggested.

Comment: But it will have to be a custom bit, because I don't think GCC "knows about" that feature bit.  It doesn't stop you from using `__builtin_ia32_rdtscp()`  / `__rdtscp()` (or `rdpmc`) the way it does for most other intrinsics, when compiling for `-march=core2` or generic.  I don't think GCC "knows" which CPUs support it, and definitely doesn't define any macros with `-march=native` vs. baseline.

Comment: @PeterCordes Right. I've posted an answer there.

Comment: @HadiBrais [According to LIBC](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=benchtests/README;h=4d83a05b4b402e869b65ff6cae115b163bb8e961;hb=HEAD#l37) all processors since 2010 support it.

Comment: @Noah Incorrect. There are a few x86 processors since 2010 that don't support `RDTSCP`, such as the Intel Saltwell (all models).

Comment: @HadiBrais Ahh, I'll fix the comment. Know where I can find the documentation on intel saltwell referencing rdtscp?

Comment: @Noah Unlike the AMD docs, the Intel datasheets don't contain CPUID dumps. You can refer to [InstLatx64](https://github.com/InstLatx64/InstLatx64) instead. `RDTSCP` support is indicated by CPUID[8000_0001].EDX[27] on Intel and AMD processors.