# Are these three functions equivalent?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, rdtsc

I want to write a function to get the current timestamp. Because the __retscp(&addr) function is used directly, one parameter must be input every time. I want to write a function cutTime() in a .h file that returns the current timestamp each time. Since I don't want to lose time because of the function call process, I define it as an inline function. One uses rdtsc and the other uses rdtscp.
Are my two implementations the same as using __retscp(&addr) directly?

```
1.static inline uint64_t curTime() {
  uint64_t a, d;
  asm volatile ("mfence");
  asm volatile("rdtsc" : "=a"(a), "=d"(d) :: "rcx");
  a = (d<<32) | a;
  asm volatile ("mfence");
  return a;
}
2.static inline uint64_t curTime() {
  uint64_t a;
  asm volatile ("rdtscp" : "=a" (a));
  return a;
}

3.__rdtscp( & junk)
```

Comment: Your 2nd function is obviously unsafe: you didn't tell the compiler about clobbering RDX and RCX.  Your first function uses `rdtsc` (not p) so the asm statement doesn't touch RCX.  But anyway, look at how these inline into real callers, e.g. on https://godbolt.org/.  Also, `mfence` is very slow and not useful here (unless you want to wait for stores to complete), you want `lfence`.

Comment: last word is junk for a reason. really idk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count clock cycles with RDTSC in GCC x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887839/how-to-count-clock-cycles-with-rdtsc-in-gcc-x86)

Comment: @Groo: It's not quite *that* simple.  An `lfence` *after* `rdtsc[p]` can help reduce measurement noise in some cases. And you usually want `lfence` before rdtsc, or use `rdtscp`, if you're timing something: letting the clock-read execute out-of-order while work is still in flight might not be what you want.  Also, there can be tiny advantages to ignoring the high half of the RDTSC[P] result via inline asm, if compilers miss optimizing away some of the shift/or when you just do `uint32_t` subtraction.

Comment: [Is there any difference in between (rdtsc + lfence + rdtsc) and (rdtsc + rdtscp) in measuring execution time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59759596).  This answer on [clflush to invalidate cache line via C function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51830976) has some discussion in comments about lfence after rdtsc at the bottom of the timed region being apparently helpful.

Comment: @Peter Cordes In the second case, only rax is used. And just read its data. Why tell the compiler about clobbering RDX and RCX？

Comment: @cyj: Because [RDTSCP](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdtscp) modifies those registers, whether you want it or not!!!  The compiler needs to know what registers are affected by an `asm` statement, otherwise it will assume they're unmodified and might be keeping something important in one of them.  Never lie to your compiler; it causes hard-to-debug problems that appear to happen in other code.  If you don't 100% understand this, stay *far* away from inline asm.  Even if you *do* understand it, https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm. (You can use `_mm_lfence()` and `__rdtsc()` just fine.)