# Docker container CPU features do not match the host's ones (RDTSCP)

Tags: docker, macos, containers, virtual-machine, cpu

I am using a Docker container to run a C++ compiled executable. The Docker container is built using the latest Linux Debian distribution, while the host is a MacOS system (MacOS 12.6, on MacBook Pro 16 Latest 2019).

Within the C++ code, I call the function `__rdtscp(unsigned int *__A)` including `x86intrin.h` for monitoring purpose. Compiling and executing the application on the MacOS host it works correctly. But if I try to run it within the Docker container, I obtain a `Illegal instruction` error (it is  compiled on another physical Linux host, I need this: anyway, I can run the same executable on different Linux machines and also on the container generated by the same Docker image I use if executed on another host).

Looking deeper into the issue, I found that `__rdtscp(unsigned int *__A)` must be supported by the CPU. It should be supported by all the CPUs after 2010/2011. In fact, it seems that flag is reported within the host CPU's features (`RDTSCP`). The problem is that I cannot find it within the container CPU's features.

Note that using `__rdtsc()` it works correctly, but this is not serializable, so I want to use `__rdtscp(unsigned int *__A)`.

Following the MacOS host output of `sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu`

[image]

And this is the output of the Debian docker container of `lscpu`

[image]

Could you help me to figure out the reason of this difference? Is there a way to force Docker to provide the same host CPU's features?

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't Docker using a shared Linux VM when running on macOS? Once this was true, not sure about today.

Comment: RDTSC isn't seriali**zing**, but you can use `lfence` to serialize its execution so it is serlializ**able**.  Of course, none of the instructions, including RDTSCP, are "serializing" in technical meaning of that term, like `cpuid` or (in future CPUs) `serialize`, because that also implies draining the store buffer, not just the ROB.  And if there's anything besides ROB and SB, serializing that, too.

Comment: Also note that on paper, RDTSCP only guarantees one-way ordering.  In practice it's probably microcoded as basically `lfence` + `rdtsc`.  See also [Is there any difference in between (rdtsc + lfence + rdtsc) and (rdtsc + rdtscp) in measuring execution time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59759596)